# C++ - Min heap implementation and post order traversal

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, traversal

So I have this small program that creates a min heap and insert values based on user input. If the users says change value 10 to 20, the program should change all occurrences of 10 to 20 and then heapify. When the user gives the print command the program should traverse the tree in postorder and print all the values. So I have written program but its giving me the incorrect output when I print. What am I doing wrong here:

```
int pArray[500]; 
int i = 0;

//Definition of Node for tree
struct TNode {
    int data; 
    TNode* left;
    TNode* right;
};

void Heapify(TNode* root, TNode* child);

// Function to create a new Node in heap
TNode* GetNewNode(int data) {
    TNode* newNode = new TNode();
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->left = newNode->right = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

// To insert data in the tree, returns address of root node 
TNode* Insert(TNode* root,int data) {
    if(root == NULL) { // empty tree
        root = GetNewNode(data);
    }
    // if the left child is empty fill that in
    else if(root->left == NULL) {
        root->left = Insert(root->left,data);
    }

    // else, insert in right subtree. 
    else if(root->right == NULL){
        root->right = Insert(root->right,data);
    }

    else {
        root->left = Insert(root->left,data);
    }

    Heapify(root, root->left);
    Heapify(root, root->right);

    return root;
}

void Heapify(TNode* root, TNode* child){
   if(root != NULL && child != NULL){
        if(root->data > child->data){
            int temp = child->data;  
            child->data = root->data;
            root->data = temp;
        }
    } 
}

void Change(TNode* root,int from, int to) {

    if (root == NULL) 
        return;

    else if (root->data == from)
        root->data = to;

    Change(root->left, from, to);
    Change(root->right, from, to);

}

void postOrder(TNode* n){
  if ( n ) {
       postOrder(n->left);
       postOrder(n->right);
       pArray[i] = n->data;
       i++;
    }  
}
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, your heapify algorithm should be recursive.

Comment: What exactly do you expect to happen, and what happens instead?  Also I think you mean "but its giving me the *incorrect* output when I print".

Comment: Why are you implementing a heap as a tree? Heaps are usually implemented as arrays.

Comment: @JonathanHoward That's just an implementation detail. Recursion and iteration are equally powerful

Comment: @NiklasB. I realize that, however I don't see it as being implemented in iteration either. It's implicitly recursive through the insertion function in this implementation, but **if** I remember my data structures correctly, the heapify function needs to be called *after* the insertion–not during.

Comment: @JonathanHoward You are absolutely right.

Comment: So it seems like my approach to this problem is wrong. I guess I should use an array to implement it?

Comment: @bablzr, generally a heap is a tree structure that is representable as an array. [Try this page as a resource](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~jmor159/PLDS210/heaps.html). However, I believe if you made your Heapify function recursive, it would solve your problem.

Comment: @noobProgrammer: d-ary heaps (including binary heaps) are typically implemented as arrays. However, there are many types of heaps (splay heap, Fibonacci heap, skew heap, pairing heap, etc.) that are implemented as trees. In particular if you want to perform decrease-key operations, it's usually better to implement the heap in a tree.

Comment: @JimMischel I am aware of this, but he clearly said min-heap in the question, and his node struct is an attempt at creating that binary min-heap structure, which is why I objected.

Answer (score 2):

> What am I doing wrong here?

I'm going to assume that you've verified the heap before you print it. Your tree implementation is a bit confusing, but it looks like it should work. I would suggest, however, that the first thing you do is print the tree *before* calling your `Change` method, just to make sure that you have a valid heap.

Assuming that you have a valid heap, your `Change` method has a problem: it never calls `Heapify`. You end up changing values in the heap and not rearranging. So of course it's going to be out of order when you output it.

When you change an item's value, you have to move that node (or the node's value) to its proper final position in the tree before you change any other value. You can probably make that work with your current model (by calling `Heapify` repeatedly until the node is in its proper position). Provided that you're increasing the value. If you're decreasing the value (i.e. changing 20 to 10), then you have a problem because your code has no way to move an item up the tree.

As @noobProgrammer pointed out in his comment, a binary heap typically is implemented as an array rather than as a tree. It's a whole lot easier to implement that way, uses less memory, and is much more efficient. If you're interested in how that's done, you should read my multi-part blog series on heaps and priority queues. The first entry, [Priority queues](http://blog.mischel.com/2013/09/26/priority-queues/), describes the problem. From there you can follow the links to learn about binary heaps and how they're implemented. The code samples are in C#, but if you read the first two introductory articles and understand the concepts, you'll be able to convert to C++ without trouble.